# sql query to find the value exist in source

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query,

```
select Vendor_ID, Descr, source, Name, Parent_Vendor_ID from VENDOR;
```

Data:

```
VendorID       Descr    Source  name     Parent Vendor ID
1234          ONLINE    ABC     JACK     6666
5689          OFFSHORE  XYZ      SAM     5555
9999          SHOP      TTT     EBAY     1234
6666         ECOMMERCE  FRE    AMERICAS
```

From the above table data 5555 doesn't exist in Vendor ID field. so I need the output as below

```
VendorID    Descr      Source   name    Parent Vendor ID    EXIST
1234        ONLINE      ABC     JACK    6666                Yes
5689        OFFSHORE    XYZ     SAM    **5555               No**
9999        SHOP        TTT     EBAY    1234                Yes
6666        ECOMMERCE   FRE    AMERICAS
```

I need to find if the Parent_Vendor_ID exist in Field 1 Vendor_ID. if exist simply need a column with Yes/No. If yes YES else NO

Output should be all fields + Parent_Vendor_ID_Exist

```
select Vendor_ID, Descr, source, Name, Parent_Vendor_ID,Parent_Vendor_ID Exist
```

I tried to if else but its not returning all values. Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select v1.Vendor_ID, v1.Descr, v1.source, v1.Name, v1.Parent_Vendor_ID,
       case when v2.Vendor_ID is null 
            then 'NO'
            else 'YES' 
       end as Parent_Vendor_ID_Exist
from vendor v1
left join vendor v2 on v1.Parent_Vendor_ID = v2.Vendor_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v1.Vendor_ID
     , v1.Descr
     , v1.source
     , v1.Name
     , v1.Parent_Vendor_ID
     , nvl2(v2.vendor_id,'Yes','No') as parent_exist
  FROM VENDOR v1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vendor v2 
      ON (v1.parent_vandor_id = v2.vendor_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT Vendor_ID, Descr, source, Name, Parent_Vendor_ID,
CASE  
     WHEN 
         EXISTS( SELECT Vendor_ID FROM VENDOR v2 WHERE v1.Parent_Vendor_ID = v2.Vendor_ID)
    THEN
        'Yes'
    ELSE
        'No'
    END as "Parent_Vendor_ID Exist"
 FROM VENDOR v1;
```

let me know if this works.